# Let $A = \{ x = \{ x_k \} \in l^2 \vert x_2 = 2x_1 \}$, show that It is a closed subspace of $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A = \{ x = \{ x_k \} \in l^2 \vert x_2 = 2x_1 \}$, I want to show  that it is a closed subspace of $l^2$.

Now this is what I have done, but I am not sure if it is right.

Checking that is is a subspace is easy: I just pick $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y \in A$ and check that $\alpha x + \beta y \in A$.

Now comes the hard part. I know that if $X \subset Y$ is a subspace of Y complete, then being closed is equivalent to being complete.

I then verify it is complete and finish:

Let $x_n = \{x_{n,k}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Caychy sequence of A. 
Then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N_\epsilon$ such that $\forall n, m > N_\epsilon$

$$ \vert x_{n,k} - x_{m,k} \vert \leq \Vert x_n - x_m \Vert_2 < \epsilon $$

This tells me that: $\exists lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n,j} = x_j$ which is my candiate limit. (I know it exists because I have a Cauchy sequence in $ \mathbb{R}$ which is a complete space.

I know prove that it is indeed the limit by calculating: 
$\Vert x_n - x \Vert_2^2$.

$$ \Vert x_n - x \Vert_2^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \vert x_{n,j} - x_j \vert^2 = $$
$$ = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \vert x_{n,j} - lim_{k\to \infty}x_{k,j} \vert^2 = $$ 
$$ = lim_{k\to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{M} \vert x_{n,j} - x_{k,j} \vert^2 \leq \epsilon^2$$

I picked M finite so that I could bring out the limit, then I let it go to infinity to find that $\Vert x_n - x \Vert_2 < \epsilon$

I have some doubts because I did not use the specific definition of A to find such limit. Is there a problem in my proof?

Comment: Consider the linear functional $f$ from the space to the field, mapping $x$ to $x_2-2x_1$. It is continuous, and thus the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ is also closed.

Comment: @dan_fulea how do you know it is continuous

Comment: ... boundedness, $|f(x)-f(y)|=|(x_2-y_2)-2(x_1-y_1)|\le|x_2-y_2|+2|x_1-y_1|\le \|x-y\|+2\|x-y\|=3\|x-y\|$.

Comment: @dan_fulea I do not see how this changes my proof, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: $f(x)=x_2-2x_1$ is a continuous linear functional. So the inverse image of the closed set $\{ 0 \}$ is a closed subset of $\ell^2$.